# Connecting to a local network through iOS-device debugging

Tags: iphone, debugging

I have an application that uses a local ip-adress to connect to a soap based web-service. It works perfectly fine to debug through the simulator, however, when trying to debug the project on an actual iPhone-device it cannot reach the local network's soap-service.

Has anyone run into this and know if this is actually possible or do we need WiFi to be able to debug to a non-local ip-address, or is even that possible?

Comment: Try from Mobile Safari on the device to see if you can reach the WSDL url.

Comment: @Black Frog I tried opening up safari printing in http://localhost/myservice.asmx but it did not respond at all. I'm totally lost here.

Comment: Your device is not running your web service.  You need to change localhost to the ip address of the computer that is running IIS. For example: http://192.168.2.1/myservice.asmx

Comment: Yes, i figured that out. I just wrote it all wrong. I typed in the ip-address of the machine that uses the web service. Still, no response. :/

Comment: If you have another computer, check with that computer also.  What about the firewall on the computer running your web service? Are you running IIS?  Are you on a virtual machine?

Comment: The firewall of the soap-server machine is off, and there is currently no other machine in the network that has a similiar service set up. :z

Comment: Well it sounds like your issue is more towards your network/environment. You post some code and people will be able to help you.  But trying to troubleshoot your IIS/web service, that will be tough.

Comment: Yes, i think so too. I'll probably delete this question and make a more informative one. Thanks for your interest though.

Comment: No problem.  You can give it a day before deleting this question.  In the meantime you can create your new questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not access your local ip address from 3G only on wifi. You access it from 3G you need an public ip on the server that you have the web service.

Answer (score 0):

If you are connected to a common wifi network say eg office wifi or home network. 
You can check the local ip of your computer for that network by ipconfig of ifconfig. 
Use same ip on app. You will be able to access. 
Cheers.